# OmniThread: ThreadPool stops working

Tags: multithreading, delphi, threadpool, omnithreadlibrary

There is this strange error i am encountering where omnithread stops scheduling tasks and just stops working...

Here is the code to reproduce the error i am having

```
Procedure PerformOperations(const task: IOmniTask);
Begin
  Sleep(1000);
End;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to 200 do
  CreateTask(PerformOperations).
            UnObserved.Schedule(ThreadPool);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ThreadPool := CreateThreadPool('ThreadPool');
  ThreadPool.MaxExecuting := 60;
  ThreadPool.MaxQueued := 0;
end;
```

When i click on the button it creates 200 tasks fine, but while looking at the thread count from task manager, as soon as the threads starts decreasing if i click on button1 that moment then thread count suddenly drops to 0 and after that no matter how many times i click on button1 for scheduling tasks no thread is created and no function is performed. i actually encountered this error while sending data to server which schedule the tasks, i wasnt able to separate the server code areas so i just wrote a sample for generating the issue at user end. Can anyone help me on how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the code for Schedule Button?

Comment: I think it is Button1?  But we can only guess offcourse...

Comment: Yes Button1, thats the button which schedule the task... sorry i thought that was obvious. Edited my question